# Commutator with identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

For an operator $A$, is $[A,\textbf{1}] = \textbf{1}$ or $\textbf{0}$ where $\textbf{1}$ is the identity operator? I think it is $\textbf{0}$ but I want to confirm this.

Comment: What problem do you have in figuring this out from the definition of the commutator?

Comment: I just wanted to confirm with someone else since I couldn't find a source online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can check this by just explicitly checking the definition of a commutator.
$$[A, \mathbf{1}] = A \cdot \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{1}\cdot A = A - A =\mathbf{0}$$

There are some exotic algebras where the *left-identity* is different from the *right-identity*; however, almost always they are equal, then we just call it the *identity* and the above relation holds.